# The following error occurs during data registration, but the cause cannot be found

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, asynchronous

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

```
// 発注登録
let orderRegister = document.getElementById("yes");
let memoData = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
orderRegister.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (qr_code.value !== "" && orderAmount.value !== "" && confirmationText.innerHTML === "登録しますよろしいですか？") {
        let handOverDate = new Date(handOver.value);
        let parameter = {
            requestType: 4,
            orderDate: orderDate.value,
            product_id: product_id,
            expectedDate: expectedDate.value,
            handOver: handOverDate,
            orderAmount: next_focus.value,
            memoData: memoData.value,
            supplierName: supplierName,
            currentDate: currentDate,
            supplierID: supplierID,
            deadLine: deadLine
        }
        postData(url, parameter, function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                alert(error);
            } else {
                if (data.status === "error") {
                    document.getElementById("supplier_name").innerHTML = "";
                    myFunction();
                    modalClose();
                    qr_code.value = "";
                    orderDate.value = "";
                    expectedDate.value = "";
                    handOver.value = "";
                    productName.innerHTML = "";
                    modalName.innerHTML = "";
                    inputNumber.innerHTML = "";
                    memoData.value = "";
                    orderLot.innerHTML = "";
                    orderAmount.value = "";
                    main_element[0].classList.remove('show');
                    none_div.style.display = "block";
                    display_info_element.classList.remove("change-style");
                }
            }
        })
    } else if (confirmationText.innerHTML === "登録しますよろしいですか？") {
        alert("発注数をご入力くださいませ。");
        modalClose();
    }

});

// 登録結果を確認する
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
    x.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function () { x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
}
// モーダルウィンドウを閉じる
function modalClose() {
    modal.classList.add("modal-hidden");
    overlay.classList.add("overlay-hidden");
}
```

```
function postData(url, data, callback) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                let response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                callback(null, response);
            } else {
                callback(new Error('ネットワークに接続されていません。接続を確認してもう一度お試しください。'));
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

When tested in the local environment, it runs properly, but when tested on the server side, the above error occurs.

I don't think it's an error on the backend side, but due to circumstances, I can't test the server side myself.

I am thinking that there may be a problem with asynchronous processing, but if there is anyone who has experience with this error, I would like to ask for help.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is not a promise. To have one you can use the fetch API. You could debug the request via network panel in the browser (hit F12).